# Ban the phrase "I spent almost a couple of hours" please

Tags: discussion

Every time I see that I really cringe. I have no idea what to make of it: ["I spent almost a couple of hours" on XYZ.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DipJT.png)

Do we give you bonus points? I have no clue what people expect, but it's sounds like and attempt at wringing sympathy from us.

Comment: Just edit and remove.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - well, I know. it's just the idea though

Comment: To be fair, part of the downvote tooltip says questions should "show research effort."

Comment: SO is working hard on improving the front page, trying to give good questions better views.  Banning phrases that are such an excellent quality indicator would be rather a mistake :)

Comment: I personally would like to ban all sentences beginning with "So" - "So I have some code...", "So I get this exception when...". We all have pet peeves but I doubt SO can cater for all of them.

Comment: Most statements beginning with "so" can be edited out or edited to make clearer.

Comment: So this sentence should be banned, @DanielKelley? :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am well aware of that - and I often do. I wasn't proposing my suggestion be implemented - was just saying there are many words/phrases people won't like and we can't automate the exclusion of all of them.

Comment: @bluefeet Haha. Touche!

Comment: That, and 'I looked on the net and couldn't find anything' as the first line of the question body. Inevitably, googling the question title returns something like 'About 5,170,000 results' :(

Comment: To be fair, I think statements like "I Googled and couldn't find anything" are a direct result of receiving pointless comment replies of "Did you try Googling? I see X million results." At least for the few questions I've asked, by the time I post here my Google-fu has been exhausted and I genuinely need another set of eyes on the problem. Comment replies like that are not constructive and somewhat patronizing.

Comment: @DaveRager: usually when I see such comments, the OP would have literally found their answer on Stack Overflow by typing their question title into Google.

Comment: I'd rather be thought of as patronizing than gullible.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that SO contributors are being used as an interface to search engines, either because OP's cannot be bothered to do their own searches when a free service is available from those suckers on SO, or to provide unique homework answers for copy/paste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are going to be too many different subtle variations in the phrasing of such a sentences to meaningfully ban it.  In trying to generalize the logic enough to actually catch a large percentage of such phrases you'd just end up banning appropriate content.

There really isn't an effective alternative to just editing such content out.

Comment: Understood, Ok i'll rest my case. thanks !